# lack of Secure Tab URL error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I keep getting the error below even though I do have a secure tab url, and it is updated in the page settings..
(I have installed the ssl today, and when I try entering the website via Https It works)

Please Update Your Secure Tab URL
To make sure users can view your app over a secure browser connection (https), please visit the developer console to update your Secure Tab URL.

Comment: You need both a HTTP and HTTPS URL for canvas and page tab apps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a real SSL cert (costs money) rather than a self-signed cert (free) to be in compliance.

Comment: Can you explain your "It works" when you enter the website via https, but also you say you get an error message when you enter into your website.  I'm very confused.